# Tunneling HTTP request over SSH

Tags: ssh, tunnel, proxy

I'm having this webserver inside my network behind a firewall. I also have this VPS outside my network, which is publicly reachable. Now, I was wondering if it would be possible to tunnel a connection between these two via SSH so if people would go to my VPS with their webbrowsers they could see the content on my webserver.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At private server run 'SSH reverse tunnel' to your public VPS:

1.1.1.1 = VPS public IP address

ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 vpsuser@1.1.1.1

Then any connection to port 8080 from your public VPS will be forwarded to port 80 of your private server.

More details here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work